# IBM Bluemix : Bulk load data into MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, ibm-cloud, bulk-load

I have created a MongoDB service in Bluemix and I can successfully access it in an app deployed on Bluemix. I can create data in the MongoDB instance programmatically through my app, but what I I want to do is load data into MongoDB from my laptop.

I am not able to ping the MongoDB web address from my laptop, so I can not connect it from a standalone java program.

What is the way ahead to bulk load data into MongoDB on Bluemix ?

Comment: Well a quick search finds be a short post linking to another post on [setting up ssh access](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2014/07/16/easy-ssh-sessions-bluemix/). So if you can set up ssh, then you can ssh tunnel. But then this becomes something other than a programming tools question. With that link in mind, you might get some more insight by posting to [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) instead,  where you are likely to get the ear of server admins and network people who likely have experience in this area.

Comment: MongoDB is just a DBaaS on Bluemix. Can you please let us know which DBaaS offering you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can not connect to this experimental service from outside of Bluemix.**

**mongodb**: You can not connect to this experimental service from outside of Bluemix. If you want to use your standalone java program to interact with this service on Bluemix, consider pushing your standalone java program as another application to Bluemix.

`cf push mystandaloneapp -p standalone.jar --no-route`

Then, bind the same mongodb instance to this application. When you restage the application, it should get the credentials in the VCAP_SERVICES environment variable.

**mongolab**: Assuming you created the `mongolab` service, from your Bluemix Dashboard, find and click on your MongoLab instance. From there, launch the MongoLab Dashboard. Click on your deployment (IbmCloud_***). You should see instructions on how to connect to mongo from shell, as well as import/export commands.

`mongoimport -h ds049570.mongolab.com:49570 -d IbmCloud_ee4rm8hq_ecl23uf8 -c <collection> -u <user> -p <password> --file <input file>`

You should also be able to connect to this from your java program.

Finally, check out the **MongoDB by Compose** service, which is an IBM provided MongoDB service, with a dashboard.

Comment: Looks like this one line is the answer :- "You can not connect to this experimental service from outside of Bluemix".